# Google Maps V2 not shown on real devices

Tags: java, android, google-maps, samsung-mobile

Hi I wrote a program with Google Maps API V2 .
this program run on emulator But when run on real devices I see only white screen whit Google logo and Zoom buttons .
What is the problem ?
my phone is Samsung galaxy s2. 
thanks ;)

Comment: Any error in the logcat?

Comment: Does the Google Maps app work on the device?

Comment: does your phone is connected to internet

Comment: error in my logcat:08-31 14:58:57.170: E/jdwp(16887): Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe

Comment: @CommonsWare It's run but shown only  a white screen

Comment: @sunil yes it is important?

Answer (score 0):

Since the Google Maps app does not work on the device, your app will suffer from the same problems. That could be a problem with your ability to access the Google Maps servers (e.g., firewall issues), or it could be a problem with the device (e.g., flawed ROM mod).

Regardless, until you get Google's own Maps app to work on your device, there is little you are likely to be able to do to help your own app.